# HTTPClient returning HttpRequestException WinRT

Tags: c#, json, windows-runtime, httpclient

For some reason, I'm receiving a **403: Forbidden** exception in Visual Studio when I try fetching JSON results from a web API I'm using. When I try using the web API URL in my web browser, everything shows up as it should. Any ideas?

*The main code:*

```
        theURI = "http://isitup.org/duckduckgo.com.json";
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
        var jsonResponse = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(theURI);

        var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StatusMessage.RootObject>(jsonResponse);
        int statuscode = rootObject.status_code;

        if (statuscode == 1)
        {
            txtStatus.Text = "Website is UP!";
        }
        else if (statuscode == 2)
        {
            txtStatus.Text = "Website is DOWN!";
        }
        else
        {
            txtStatus.Text = "Invalid domain!";
        }
```

*and the class file*

```
class StatusMessage
{
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string domain { get; set; }
        public int port { get; set; }
        public int status_code { get; set; }
        public object response_ip { get; set; }
        public object response_code { get; set; }
        public object response_time { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well presumably your browser is sending some sort of authentication...

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, thought about that, but I can't figure out where that would be.

Comment: Well use Wireshark or something similar to see *exactly* what your browser is sending.

Comment: Tried using Live HTTP Headers for Firefox to check for auth keys or something similar, but couldn't find anything. Could Wireshark show me anything more specific? I don't think WinCap can be installed on Windows 8.

Comment: 1. Check cookies. Your browser may send them and your app don't.
2. Try to change user agent, maybe default one is banned by server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the server responds you 403 if you are using the default user agent. If you change it to chrome user agent the server is answering properly.

```
var url = new Uri("http://isitup.org/duckduckgo.com.json");
var req = new HttpClient();
var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
message.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1309.0 Safari/537.17");
var response = await req.SendAsync(message);
var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Works just like it should! Thanks, Teemu.

Comment: Ran into this when trying to use bing maps location api.  Thanks!